# Python Async Functions won't Give up the CPU

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, concurrency, fastapi

I have two async functions that both need to run constantly and one of them just hogs all of the CPU.

The first function handles receiving websocket messages from a client.

```
    async def handle_message(self, ws):
        """Handles a message from the websocket."""
        logger.info('awaiting message')
        while True:
            msg = await ws.receive()
            logger.debug('received message: %s', msg)
            jmsg = json.loads(msg['text'])
            logger.info('received message: {}'.format(jmsg))
            param = jmsg['parameter']
            val = jmsg['data']['value']
            logger.info('setting parameter {} to {}'.format(param, val))
            self.camera.change_parameter(param, val)
```

The second function grabs images from a camera and sends them to the frontend client. This is the one that one that won't give the other guy any time.

```
    async def send_image(self, ws):
        """Sends an image to the websocket."""
        for im in self.camera:
            await asyncio.sleep(1000)
            h, w = im.shape[:2]
            resized = cv2.resize(im, (w // 4, h // 4))
            await ws.send_bytes(image_to_bytes(resized))
```

I'm executing these coroutines using `asyncio.gather()`. The decorator is from FastAPI and `Backend()` is my class that contains the two async coroutines.

```
@app.websocket('/ws')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    """Handle a WebSocket connection."""
    backend = Backend()
    logger.info('Started backend.')
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        aws = [backend.send_image(websocket), backend.handle_message(websocket)]
        done, pending = await asyncio.gather(*aws)

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await websocket.close()
```

Both of these coroutines will operate seperately, but if I try to run them together `send_image()` never gives any time to `handle_message` and so none of the messages are ever received (or at least that's what I think is going on).

I thought this is what `asyncio` was trying to solve, but I'm probably using it wrong. I thought about using multiprocessing, but I'm pretty sure FastAPI expects awaitables here. I also read about using the return variables from `gather()`, but I didn't really understand. Something about canceling the `pending` tasks and adding them back to the event loop.

Can anyone show me the correct (and preferably modern pythonic) way to make these async coroutines run concurrently?

Comment: I think your asyncio code is correct, could you check that `send_image` is not stuck into an infinite loop, a regular blocking call or some other unexpected CPU intensive work? For instance, maybe the camera or the web socket is not initialized and this causes some issue.